# List in NavigationView is calling init for every row

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-mac

I'm making a Mac app using SwiftUI.

I have a simple 2 column NavigationView.  The first view is a Sidebar containing a list, the second view is a detail view.

(I know NavigationView has been deprecated, but I can't use NavigationSplitView at the moment.)

When I launch the app, the init function on the detail view is being called for every row of the list (in toy example below, init 1-10 is printed to console).  Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong? In my real app, the init is used to create a core data fetch request, so calling it multiple times unnecessarily is undesirable.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            EmptyView()

        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach((1...10), id: \.self){ i in
                NavigationLink{
                    DetailView(myVar: i)
                } label: {
                    Text("myVar \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    @State var preVar:Int
    init(myVar: Int) {
        let _ = print("init \(myVar)")
        self.preVar = myVar
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, but it's only the `init` that is called, so it's very lightweight.

The `body` var is only called when the View is displayed.

This doesn't happen when using the new iOS 16 `NavigationStack` as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            SidebarView(path: $path)
            EmptyView()

        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach((1...10), id: \.self){ i in
                NavigationLink("myVar \(i)", value: i)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { i in
            DetailView(myVar: i)
        }
    }
}
```